# Meteor: Pulling variable from iron router to a template

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I am trying to get two variable from the **iron router** so that I can essentially call them in my temlate such as `{{user.telephone}}` and `{{pic.profilepic}}`.
My code in the router is as follows. (Does Not Work!)

```
Router.route('/profile/:_id', {
name: 'profile',
template: 'profile',
data:function(){
    return {
        user:Info.findOne({_id:this.params._id}),
        pic: Profilepics.findOne({_id:this.params._id})
    };
   },
subscriptions: function(){
    return {
        Meteor.subscribe("userInfo"),
        Meteor.subscribe( "profilepic");
},
action:function (){
    if (this.ready()){
        this.render();
    }else {
        this.render('loading');
    }
  }

});
```

I able to do just one variable with the following code. i.e get `{{user.telephone}}`. Any chance anyone can help me get both variable instead of just one?

```
enterRouter.route('/profile/:_id', {
name: 'profile',
template: 'profile',
data:function(){
    return {
        user:Info.findOne({_id:this.params._id})
    };
   },
subscriptions: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe("userInfo")
},
action:function (){
    if (this.ready()){
        this.render();
    }else {
        this.render('loading');
    }
  }
 });
```

Comment: Try to returning multiple subscriptions as an array `return [
        Meteor.subscribe("userInfo"),
        Meteor.subscribe( "profilepic")
];`

Comment: Are you sure that both the collections having the same `_id` ? `Profilepics` may be having diff id.

Comment: yes they do.100% sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return multiple subscriptions as an array from `subscriptions` function,

Use  `return [
        Meteor.subscribe("userInfo"),
        Meteor.subscribe( "profilepic")
];`

instead of

`return { Meteor.subscribe("userInfo"), Meteor.subscribe( "profilepic");` which has `{}` mismatch.

Comment: What about this part,
return {
        user:Info.findOne({_id:this.params._id}),
        pic: Profilepics.findOne({_id:this.params._id})
    };
I am able to use one variable, (user or pic) at a time but not both together. Any idea why that is?

Comment: That part is okay, you can return an object as data context, Verify the subscriptions by running the query in browser console

Comment: yes I verfied the subscription. Additionally if i just use 
return {
            user:Info.findOne({_id:this.params._id})
        }; 
it works, also if i do the same for pics it works, but together it does not work

Comment: try to print `this.data` in console.log, from Template.profile.rendered

Comment: Hmm, its working. Dont know what I was doing wrong yesterday. Is seems to work fine today. But passing the subscribe as arrary using [...] defnitly works!!
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the latest version of iron router, i suggest you update the code to something a bit more modern.

First you create a general app controller:

```
ApplicationController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'DefaultLayout',
    loadingTemplate: 'loading_template',
    notFoundTemplate: '404_template',
});
```

Then you start to extend it for different purposes:

```
ProfileController = ApplicationController.extend({
    show_single: function() {
        this.render('profile');
    }
});
```

After this you can create your routes for the profile part

```
Router.route('/profile/:_id', {
    controller: 'ProfileController',
    action: 'show_single',
    waitOn: function() {
        return [
            Meteor.subscribe("userInfo"),
            Meteor.subscribe("profilepic")
        ];
    },
    subscriptions: function() {
        this.subscribe("somethingyoudontneedtowaitfor", this.params._id);
    },
    data: function() {
        if (this.ready()) {
            return {
                user: Info.findOne({
                    _id: this.params._id
                }),
                pic: Profilepics.findOne({
                    _id: this.params._id
                })
            };
        }
    }
});
```

It might be a bit more code, but it gives you complete control over what it does. Also, using this, while the router is waiting for the subscriptions to be ready, it displays the loading template defined above. If you don't want to display the loading, you move the subscriptions out of waiton.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar situation I have

```
data: function() {
  var gridId = this.params._gridId;
  return (People.find({gridId: gridId})
          && GridLog.find({gridId: gridId}));
},
```

with the subscribe calls in the waitOn() handler as part of the Boolean status

```
waitOn: function() {
  return (Meteor.subscribe('people', this.params._gridId)
    && Meteor.subscribe('gridlog', this.params._gridId) );
},
```

You may have more success just &&ing them together in waitOn() (as strange as that seems).